# spyder in anaconda: Failed to create D3D shaders

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I installed Anaconda3, version=5.0.1, on the computer server , which is 64 bit win8 operating system. 
and when I open the spyder It prompted firstly:

```
PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

and I use pip installing pyqt5, version=5.10, to solve it,but finally appeared:

```
QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.

shader compilation failed:
"Failed to create D3D shaders.\n"
QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.

QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(qt_Matrix): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.

shader compilation failed:
"Failed to create D3D shaders.\n"
QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.

QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(qt_Matrix): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.

shader compilation failed:
"Failed to create D3D shaders.\n"
QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.

QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(matrix): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(opacity): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.
```

Comment: might be related: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3226

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest DirectX drivers. That worked for me.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I want to point out that the OP's problem is related to graphics card drivers and that updating DirectX is one of the best solutions to solve it (the other is updating your graphics drivers). Thanks Ashish for your answer!